# Exception handling with phpunit and Silex

Tags: php, phpunit, functional-testing, silex

I am using a route in Silex to delete an object from the database. If an object does not exist, a 404 error should be thrown. This works fine in the browser, and the response is received accordingly.

This is my source:

```
$app->delete("/{entity}/{id}", function(\Silex\Application $app, HttpFoundation\Request $request, $entity, $id) {
    // some prep code is here
    $deleteObject = $this->em->getRepository($entityClass)->find($id);
    if (empty($deleteObject))
        $app->abort(404, "$ucEntity with ID $id not found");
    // other code comes here...
}
```

This is my test case:

```
// deleting the same object again should not work
$client->request("DELETE", "/ccrud/channel/$id");
$this->assertTrue($response->getStatusCode() == 404);
```

Now phpunit fails with the following error:
    1) CrudEntityTest::testDelete
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: Channel with ID 93 not found

I can see from the message that the 404 was thrown, but I cannot test the response object as planned. I know that in theory I could assert for the exception itself, but that is not what I want to do, I want to get the response (as a browser would do as well) and test for the status code itself.

Anybody any ideas how to reach that or if there is a better way to test this?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

This is how it is being done in the tests of Silex itself ([see here](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/tests/Silex/Tests/ErrorHandlerTest.php#L58)):

```
public function testErrorHandlerNotFoundNoDebug()
{
    $app = new Application();
    $app['debug'] = false;

    $request = Request::create('/foo');
    $response = $app->handle($request);
    $this->assertContains('<title>Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.</title>', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertEquals(404, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```